# How to find strings beginning with X?

Tags: regex, stata

I am trying to identify strings that begin with `X` using the function `regexm()` in Stata.

My code:

```
for var lookin: count if regexm(X, "X")
```

I have tried using double quotes, square brackets, adding the options for the other characters in the string `X[0-9][0-9]` etc. but to no avail.

I expect the resultant number to be about `1000`, but it returns `0`.

Comment: Please read the [Stata tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info) for advice on how to ask questions on here. You need to provide a data example and code that replicates the problem when run on said data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
clear
input str22 foo
"Xhello"
"this is a X sentence"
"X a silly one"
"but serves the purpose"
end

generate tag = strmatch(foo, "X*")

list

     +------------------------------+
     |                    foo   tag |
     |------------------------------|
  1. |                 Xhello     1 |
  2. |   this is a X sentence     0 |
  3. |          X a silly one     1 |
  4. | but serves the purpose     0 |
     +------------------------------+

count if tag
2
```

This is the regular expression solution based on the above example:

```
generate tag = regexm(foo, "^X")
```

Answer (score 1):

`for` in Stata is ancient and now undocumented syntax, unless you are using a very old version of Stata, in which case you would be better flagging that.

`X` is the default loop element which is substituted everywhere it is found.

Hence your syntax -- looping over a single variable -- reduces to

```
count if regexm(lookin, "lookin")
```

and even without a data example we can believe that the answer is 0.

This would be legal and is closer to what you seek:

```
for Y in var lookin : count if regexm(Y, "X")
```

but the regular expression is wrong, as @Pearly Spencer points out.

Incidentally,

```
count if strpos(lookin, "X") == 1
```

is a direct alternative to your code.

In any Stata that supports `regexm()` you should be looping with `foreach` or `forvalues`.